# SQLSRV PDO connection with domain

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have a problem when I try to connect with SQLSRV PDO with a server and user en domain. I put like this:

```
<?php
try{
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=instsql.domain\\instsql;Database=DatabaseName", "user@instsql.domain", "userpass");
}catch (PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
```

But when I test it, the browser send me this error:

> SQLSTATE[28000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
>   Server]Login failed for user 'user@instsql.domain'.

The user is in the Active Directory, is the first time that I use SQLSRV PDO with domain users, I hope you can help me.

Comment: I have not used the `SQLSRV` driver however when I use `dblib` to connect to a MS SQL server using PDO I do something like this: `$conn = new PDO('dblib:host=MYHOST;dbname=MYDB', 'mydomain\myuser', 'password');` - notice how I format the username with the domain? My suggestion is to try that format instead of `user@domain`.

Comment: I tried but didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is that you need to stop the apache service, go to properties and in the section of start session, add your user and password. Start apache services and you connect SQL Server with the domain user.